# How to extract a negative number from a string

Tags: c

I need help extracting numbers from a char.
Lets say I have:

```
char str = "   ( 1   22  -4)";
```

I need to extract each integer and call another method.

```
while (*p) {
     if (isdigit(*p)) {
         int val = strtol(p, &p, 10);
         on_int(val);
     } else {
         p++;
     }
 }
```

I have extracted the integers successfully but I cannot figure out how to extract negatives.

With this code I have extracted 1, 22, and 4. How do I get that negative infront of the 4?

Comment: I don't understand the question, exactly - if the first character is '-', can't you multiply your result by -1?  However, this starts to beg the question as to whether --4, ---4, etc. should be allowed as input.

Comment: thanks for the formatting help! I couldn't figure it out!

Comment: The formatting is just [markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the condition to accommodate the minus, like this:

```
if ((p[0] == '-' && isdigit(p[1]))|| isdigit(p[0])) ...
```

Comment: It might be a bit simpler to say `if ((*p == '-' && isdigit(p[1])) || isdigit(*p))`. This way you don't have to compare the end pointer at all.

Comment: @KevinBallard You're right, it works even in the end position! This is now updated. Thanks!

Comment: suppose we have:
    `char str = "----1"`
This detects 4 different numbers. How do you get around this?

Comment: No it doesn't dLiGHT. `"--"` would fail this condition `p[0] == '-' && isdigit(p[1]))` because p[1] isn't a digit.

Answer (score 0):

```
  while (*p) {
       if (isdigit(*p) || ( (*p == '-' || *p == '+')  && isdigit(*(p+1)) )) {
           int val = strtol(p, &p, 10);
           on_int(val);
       } else {
           p++;
       }
   }
```